# What's It - Found in a Yard in South-Central Pennsylvania

Tags: identification

I found these flowers in my neighbor's yard. Not planted by them, they can't it together enough to have a garden. What are they ? I haven't seen them in my area Pennsylvania in the past.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a spring flowering bulbous perennial called Ipheion uniflorum, though there is now some argument about its name and classification - more info here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipheion_uniflorum

There are named varieties of this plant, ranging in colour from bluish white to blue, and the flowers are usually honey scented. Often produces its leaves in autumn, but more usually spring, before the flowers.